# Resurrecting MFC/Visual Studio 6.0 project in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to build a MFC Visual Studio 6.0 project in Visual Studio 2010.
The compiler gives me an error:

> error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall
>   ProgressDialog::* )(void)' to 'LRESULT (__thiscall CWnd::*
>   )(WPARAM,LPARAM)'
>
> //--------------------------------- // Message map
>
> BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(ProgressDialog, CDialog)    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_CANCEL,
>   OnCancelClicked)  **ON_MESSAGE**(MSG_FINISHED, OnFinished)
>   END_MESSAGE_MAP()

Any suggestions - ?

Pedro

Answer (score 9):

Change your ON_MESSAGE macro to ON_MESSAGE_VOID. The ON_MESSAGE macro returns a LRESULT from receiving WPARAM and LPARAM arguments.  Your compiler error message states that your OnFinished() method is void arguments returning void.  That's what the ON_MESSAGE_VOID macro handles.

**ADDITION:**

Refer to bottom of [C++ Q & A -- Microsoft Systems Journal July 1999](https://www.microsoft.com/msj/0799/c/c0799.aspx)

Comment: Totally undocumented - nice find.

Comment: Well, Paul DiLascia had an article on it years ago... I've been at it too long if I can remember Paul DiLascia.

Comment: My applause. You saved my day. I had also to remove an ampersand **&** I had before the function in the second parameter of the macro.

Answer (score 1):

There were [breaking changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1sc4t4k%28VS.90%29.aspx) in MFC7.0, including:

> The function parameter in the `ON_MESSAGE` macro must match the type
>
> `afx_msg LRESULT (CWnd::*)(WPARAM, LPARAM)`

Your `ProgressDialog::OnFinished` method needs to now return an `LRESULT`.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my post 

Tried changing the return type to LRESULT in both the definition and declaration of Onfinished - but now I get 


'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'LRESULT (__thiscall ProgressDialog::* )(void)' to 'LRESULT (__thiscall CWnd::* )(WPARAM,LPARAM)'

Comment: You also need to add the (WPARAM, LPARAM) parameters to the definition and declaration of your function.