# Does exist a ON_COMMAND_EX version accepting a function returning void?

Tags: visual-c++, command, void, return-type, message-map

I searched but I didn't found. I want a Message map macro that links the menu item command action to a function accepting the numeric ID and providing no return at all (being void).

`ON_COMMAND` returns void, but it is too limited, because it does not provide the menu item ID, which I need in this case.

`ON_COMMAND_EX` returns a `BOOL`, so it forces me to do a lot of returns, which would be unneeded if the return type was void.

So, as I described in first paragraph, is there such a macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found such a macro but I came with a solution: Define my own macro based on the definition of `ON_COMMAND_EX`, replacing `BOOL` by `void`.

The `ON_COMMAND_EX` macro is:

```
#define ON_COMMAND_EX(id, memberFxn) \
    { WM_COMMAND, CN_COMMAND, (WORD)id, (WORD)id, AfxSigCmd_EX, \
        (AFX_PMSG) \
        (static_cast< BOOL (AFX_MSG_CALL CCmdTarget::*)(UINT) > \
    (memberFxn)) },
```

I've just copied and adapted it to my own purposes:

```
#define ON_COMMAND_EX_VOID(id, memberFxn) \
    { WM_COMMAND, CN_COMMAND, (WORD)id, (WORD)id, AfxSigCmd_EX, \
        (AFX_PMSG) \
        (static_cast< void (AFX_MSG_CALL CCmdTarget::*)(UINT) > \
    (memberFxn)) },
```

Notice the only two changes are the name of tha macro and change from `BOOL` to `void`

To use it:
On the message map, add something like

```
    ON_COMMAND_EX_VOID(ID_FILE_PREFERENCES, OnFilePreferencesVoid)
```

Then declare the handler function on the header file:
        afx_msg void OnFilePreferencesVoid(UINT nID);

And finally do the implementation on the source code file:

```
void CMainFrame::OnFilePreferencesVoid(UINT nID)
{
    CString s;
    s.Format(_T("%d"), nID);
    AfxMessageBox(s);
}
```

Obviously, the code posted here is a theoretical example, as there are more useful things to do than display an already annoying popup message with an irritant resource ID.

The inspiration for the solution came from `ON_MESSAGE_VOID` posted on https://stackoverflow.com/a/10619963/383779

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
ON_COMMAND_RANGE(ID_COMMAND, ID_COMMAND, Handler)
```

Comment: Can you explain more your answer please ?